# Image captured from camera is empty in rare scenario

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

### Sample part of Code i have used:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == Keys.CAMERA_INTENT) {
                // IMAGE IS FROM CAMERA
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals(refImage)) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                listOfImages.add(f.toString());

                try {
                    DisplayCapturedImagesFromCamera();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == 2) {
                // IMAGE IS FROM GALLERY

            }
        }
    }
```

**What is happening:**

1. Sometimes the blank image(nothing is there in image and just a place
   holder is created). when i use camera with above code

**What i am trying to do:**

1. Is there a way to check the file actually has image data in it
   before setting the image with location
2. Something like to read the contents of file for image data

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Android device and manufacturer as well as the Android version and camera app you are using, the camera intent needs to be implemented differently. Check out https://github.com/ralfgehrer/AndroidCameraUtil, in particular [CameraIntentHelperActivity](https://github.com/ralfgehrer/AndroidCameraUtil/blob/master/library/src/de/ecotastic/android/camerautil/lib/CameraIntentHelperActivity.java).